# <a href> tag on overlay div doesn't respond

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor, overlay

I have an overlay div (rb-overlay) that appears when users click on an option on the page. The overlay covers the page 100% and has a close button in the top right hand corner. At the end of the text on this overlay (See code below) I want to place a link to another page in the site. This link doesn't respond presumably because the overlay is in the way.  Any ideas?

```
<div class="rb-overlay" tabindex="5001" style="overflow: hidden; outline: none; opacity: 1; z-index: 9999; pointer-events: auto; clip: rect(0px 1434px 992px 0px);">
            <span class="rb-close">close</span>  <!-- service-content : starts -->
<div class="rb-week clearfix" style="background:#7a5c64">

                    <!-- service-matter : starts -->
                    <div class="service-matter">
                        <span style="font-size: 155.66666666666666px;">Make Up and Go</span>
                        <div id="service-carousel-01" class="carousel slide">  
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                                <div class="item active"><img alt="" title="" class="service-spec-img" src="http://myrubyslippers.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/make-up-bag@2x.jpg" width="467" height="352">
                                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="service-info">
                        <h5 class="service-spec">£20.00</h5>
                        <h3>What's involved</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur hendrerit tempor dui, vel eleifend metus. Pellentesque blandit vestibulum laoreet. Donec dapibus ligula at risus ullamcorper, nec posuere sapien malesuada. Nam tortor nulla, aliquam sit amet aliquet at, malesuada ac sapien. Nam sed diam id velit feugiat egestas vitae non lacus. Duis pulvinar, ligula sit amet rhoncus imperdiet, nisi orci mollis mauris, ut semper nunc magna ut velit.</p>

                        <a href="http://myrubyslippers.co.uk/make-up-parties/">Click here to go to Make Up Services Section</a>
                     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the div covers the anchor and the anchor becomes unclickable. 

 use the `z-index` CSS property to the anchor and set it high : 999 for example.

Comment: The anchor is in the div not covered by it. It also seems to respond to pointer events (i.e. hand cursor appears on hover) it's just nothing happens when it's clicked

Comment: Yes and the anchor has a z-index of 11000 and the rb-overlay div a z-index of 9999

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="rb-week clearfix" style="background:#7a5c64; z-index:1000;">
```

instead of

```
<div class="rb-week clearfix" style="background:#7a5c64">
```

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that the overlay is called rb-overlay and that div appears first - I missed it from my original code

    <div class="rb-overlay" tabindex="5001" style="overflow: hidden; outline: none; opacity: 1; z-index: 9999; pointer-events: auto; clip: rect(0px 1434px 992px 0px);">
                    <span class="rb-close">close</span>  <!-- service-content : starts -->
                  <div class="rb-week clearfix" style="background:#7a5c64">